# advice on improving query performance ~ 1 day

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have 5 tables - Each have tens of thousands of records

1 main/very important table (TABLE A) 
2 other tables (TABLES B/C) that still important but not as important as table

2 side tables (TABLES D/E)that hold primary keys between A<=>B and A<=>C i.e. only have two columns each

The 3 main tables have ~140 columns each, all have the same column names

The purpose of my query is to perform column level matching between all the tables A<=>D<=>B and A<=>E<=>C in one query

The final query will have about 286 columns (two ID columns from each main table,

```
select tableA.ID1 as [TABLEAID1],
    tableA.ID2 as [TABLEAID2],
    tableB.ID1 as [TABLEBID1],
    tableB.ID2 as [TABLEBID2],
    tableC.ID1 as [TABLECID1],
    tableC.ID2 as [TABLECID2],
    fn_TESTMatcher(tableA.[postCode], tableB.[postCode],) as 
        [TABLEAB.postCode.RESULT],
    fn_TESTMatcher(tableA.[CityCode], tableB.[CityCode],) as 
        [TABLEAB.CityCode.RESULT], 
.
.
. x238 more 'fn_TESTMatcher(...) as xyz' columns
.
INTO #Results
From tableA WITH (NOLOCK)
    FULL JOIN tableD WITH (NOLOCK) ON tableA.ID1 = tableD.A
        ) FULL JOIN tableB WITH (NOLOCK) ON tableD.B = tableB.ID1
            ) FULL JOIN tableE WITH (NOLOCK) ON tableA.ID1 = tableE.A
) FULL JOIN tableC WITH (NOLOCK) ON tableE.B = tableC.ID
```

fn_TESTMatcher is a function, it is fed the same column from two main tables, then it removes/replaces special characters/abbreviations, and then tries to match them, if they match it returns a bit '1', if not then a bit '0'.

at the moment it takes about a day to run (i can't really time it with some sort of query timer), I can comment out all the columns except for the last and run it and its fairly quick, but i dont think i can just scale that up

Does anyone have some advice? My first assumption is to start googling on what indexes are and ...maybe.. apply it to the ID1 of every table although I'm a bit hesitant on a) messing up my tables and b) adding an index that ends up being useless

===========================================
update 2: table structure wise all the columns for all the main tables are varchars, length 100-250 characters, where ID (primary key) is not nullable

With the two side tables, they just have two columns, both varchar, 100 character limit (they're both foreign keys). The most important table's ID in this is not nullable

for functions, i technically have two:

```
FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_TESTStripCharacters]
(
    @String NVARCHAR(MAX) ,
    @MatchExpression VARCHAR(255)
)
RETURNS NVARCHAR(MAX)
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @expres  VARCHAR(50) = '%[~,@,#,^,_,+,-,$,%,&,/,|,\,*,(,),.,!,`,:,<,>,?]%'
  WHILE PATINDEX( @expres, @String ) > 0
      SET @String = REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE( @String, SUBSTRING( @String, PATINDEX( @expres, @String ), 1 ),''),';',''),'-','')
  RETURN @String
END
```

and second function

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_TESTMatcher](@Field1 NVARCHAR(MAX), @Field2 
    NVARCHAR(MAX))
    RETURNS BIT 
    BEGIN
   SET @Field1 = UPPER(LTRIM(RTRIM(REPLACE(dbo.fn_TESTStripCharacters(@Field1,@SpecialCharacters),'-',''))))
   SET @Field2 = UPPER(LTRIM(RTRIM(REPLACE(dbo.fn_TESTStripCharacters(@Field2,@SpecialCharacters),'-',''))))
   SET @Field1 = REPLACE(@Field1,' RD ',' ROAD ')
   SET @Field2 = REPLACE(@Field2,' RD ',' ROAD ')

   SET @Field1 = REPLACE(@Field1,' ST ',' STREET ')
   SET @Field2 = REPLACE(@Field2,' ST ',' STREET ')


   SET @Field1 = REPLACE(@Field1,' ','')
   SET @Field2 = REPLACE(@Field2,' ','')


   RETURN 
          CASE WHEN @Field1=@Field2
            THEN '1'
            ELSE '0'
          END
END
```

=============================
update 2

Example table data - assuming the same two records exist in all 3 tables (not always the case )

```
TableA (main + most important table):
ID1   ID2    postCode, cityCode, ................
10001 1221   IG11PJ    London     ................
10230 1022   IG22PJ    Nottingham ................


tableB (slightly less important table)
ID1   ID2    postCode, cityCode, ................
10031 1011   IG1 1PJ    london     ................
10980 982   IG2 2PJ    nottingham ................


tableC (slightly less important table)
ID1   ID2    postCode, cityCode, ................
10551 1011   iG1 1pj    london     ................
20980 982    iG2 2pJ    nottingham ................

tableD (side table)
A         B
10001  10031 
10230  10980

table E (side table)
A        B
10001 10551  
10230 20980
```

Comment: questions seeking performance help should include DDL,DML Of the tables involved along with test data..if your test data is large,try scripting out schema and stats for the table(right click database->generate scripts->select specific database objects->in next screen select advanced and choose Script statistics) and paste it in question..With this info any one repro the same issue you are facing.Otherwise it becomes very difficult to answer your question .Pasting server version also helps

Comment: I would initially make sure you're joining the smaller tables first and then add indexes to the columns too

Comment: if you run this query in SSMS with option 'show actual execution plan' than is there any advice from SSMS about your query ?

Comment: Why are you trying to do this in a single query? Your functions will be killing it. What is the end result that you are trying to acheive - are you trying to find duplicate rows? compare two tables? something else?

Comment: ID1 isn't indexed?? Please try indexing it and see if it helps. Index will hurt performance of an insert, but shouldn't do anything else you don't want it to do.

Comment: http://blogs.sqlsentry.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere/

Comment: Also, scalar functions are horrible for performance and even worse when they are columns in your queries. You seem to be doing this a LOT in here. It sounds like you have 240 columns being populated per row using a scalar function. That means 240 executions per row. No wonder it is slow.

Comment: @NickFry The point is that all 3 main tables should ideally be the same. The query will be filled with 1's and 0's to show which columns match and which don't.  if there are 10,000 records and for a certain column it is filled with all 0's then that's an issue (e.g. maybe the logic is off).As an example in tableA, the phone field could have 1111-123-4567, but in tableB it's 1111 - 123 - 4567. My  fn_TESTMatcher might remove all the hyphens but not the spaces so column tableAB.phone.RESULT would be 0

Comment: @sagi I was thinking of a cluster index, but i'm comparing ALL the fields, likewise, i could use a non-cluster index, but there are 240 columns that wont be using the non clusted index field. so I'm in a bad position either way???

Comment: No matter how much debating happens here without the table structures and the ddl for that scalar function the best anybody can do is guess. I suspect just changing that scalar function to an inline table valued function will help immensely.

Comment: Note that using NOLOCK can give you incorrect results... usually if you are doing a query you want accurate results, so don't use NOLOCK...

Comment: @SeanLange i've updated the OP, does that help?

Comment: Can you provide sample data for all 5 tables along with the result set you are looking for?

Comment: @Aducci i added some test data in OP now

Comment: @user3120554 - Can you also include your desired results?

Answer (score 0):

If Tables A, B, and C should be identical save for formatting differences I would suggest you create 3 CTEs, the first selecting TableA ID and a `HASHBYTES` of all other columns (columns will need to be cast to char/varchar so any formatting and replacing can take place there), the second CTE the same for Table B and the third for Table C.

Then just match the HASHBYTES values.
As has already been said though, without sample data, table structures, DDL for the function etc. we are just guessing.

Sean and Milney both make very good points regarding scalar vs inline table function and use of NOLOCK

Comment: I'll also look into your answer, to confirm, CTE is a "common table expression"?

Answer (score 0):

I see these as a task that does not belong in one query.  I would create a new set of tables (or these tables is you have a backup/don't need to preserve the data) and then perform your data cleaning steps into those new tables.

Once you have happy the data has been normalized then do a single query to compare the tables.

Trying to put it all in one query gives no advantage and you don't step wise make progress.  For example, if you find you forgot to strip spaces out of once field you have to redo EVERYTHING.  If you make new tables with the "cleaned" data you can incrementally invest time on cleaning the data (which is clearly the slow part of this process) till the data is perfect and then run your quick comparison.  Forgot something -- it is a relatively quick update and run.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of all the headaches you are running through, making copies of everything, and then trying to parse based on functions that can not be optimized, I would suggest the following.  You state you have a column that gets stripped of special characters.  I would add a "CleanKey" column for each table and represented column.  Then, via a possible table trigger, or before the add/save, pre-clean that value into the "CleanKey" column and you are done.  Then have an index on THOSE "Clean" columns and do a direct join.

Since the rest of the system does not know of these "Clean" columns, you can add the columns, clean them out of whatever function you have and not worry about duplicating or otherwise ruining other data.

Yes, it may take a bit to pre-"Clean" these columns, but then its DONE.  Your query should be fast after that.

Answer (score 0):

I would agree with the others that cleaning these string values would be a good idea. But since you still need to accomplish that and I absolutely hate loops and scalar functions with a passion I decided to roll up an inline table valued function instead of these two nested scalar functions. I am not using any loops here and the performance might surprise you.

I am using a tally or numbers table for this. I like to keep one of these around as view. Here is the code for the view I use.

```
create View [dbo].[cteTally] as

WITH
    E1(N) AS (select 1 from (values (1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1))dt(n)),
    E2(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E1 a, E1 b), --10E+2 or 100 rows
    E4(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E2 a, E2 b), --10E+4 or 10,000 rows max
    cteTally(N) AS 
    (
        SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) FROM E4
    )
select N from cteTally
GO
```

Then you can use this tally table to derive a set based approach to accommodate the business rules you have for deciding if two values match. You also don't need comma delimiters in here. In your example you had a comma nearly every other character in the list of values to remove. A single instance of each character is sufficient.

```
create function [dbo].[fn_TESTMatcher_Sean]
(
    @Field1 nvarchar(max)
    , @Field2 nvarchar(max)
    , @CharsToRemove nvarchar(max)
) returns table as 
    RETURN

    with MyValues1 as
    (
        select substring(@Field1, N, 1) as MyChar
            , t.N
        from cteTally t 
        where N <= len(@Field1)
            and charindex(substring(@Field1, N, 1), @CharsToRemove) = 0
    )
    , MyValues2 as
    (
        select substring(@Field2, N, 1) as MyChar
            , t.N
        from cteTally t 
        where N <= len(@Field2)
            and charindex(substring(@Field2, N, 1), @CharsToRemove) = 0
    )

    select convert(bit, case when mv1.MyResult = mv2.MyResult then 1 else 0 end) as IsMatch
    from
    (
        select distinct MyResult = 
        replace(
            replace(replace(STUFF((select MyChar + ''
                    from MyValues1 mv2
                    order by mv2.N
                    FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE).value('.','NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 0, '')
                    , ' RD ', ' ROAD ')
                    , ' ST ', ' STREET ')
                    , ' ', '')
        from MyValues1 mv
    ) mv1
    cross join
    (
        select distinct MyResult = 
    replace(
        replace(replace(STUFF((select MyChar + ''
                from MyValues2 mv2
                order by mv2.N
                FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE).value('.','NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 0, '')
                , ' RD ', ' ROAD ')
                , ' ST ', ' STREET ')
                , ' ', '')
    from MyValues2 mv
    ) mv2
    ;
```

Give this a shot and let me know if this works in your environment.

For example:

```
select *
from fn_TESTMatcher_Sean('123 any st rd or something', '123 any street road or something', '%[~,@#^_+-$%&/|\*().!`:<>?]%')
```

The above returns 1 because they are a match under the rules you defined.